# How sending and receiving works in Python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, send

I'm working with python sockets for a while, and I wrote some simple programs.

The problem that I encountered is related to sending/receiving methods in python sockets.
Giving you a basic example:

This is the receiver (server):

> ```
> import socket
> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> s.bind(('', 4001))
> s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
> s.listen(5)
>
>
> while True:
>   conn, addr = s.accept()
>   print conn, addr
>
>   data1 = conn.recv(64)
>   data2 = conn.recv(64)
>
>   print 'uname is %s , password is: %s' %(data1, data2, )
>   conn.close()
> ```

And this is the sender (or client):

> ```
> import socket
> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> s.connect(('', 4001))
>
> uname = raw_input('enter username>')
> passw = raw_input('enter password>')
>
> s.send(uname)
> s.send(passw)
>
> print 'exiting ...'
> s.close()
> ```

So the problem is: why server receives both uname and passw in first s.recv() method? It means data2 is always empty!

I have no idea what happens when client executes the `s.send()` method. I was thinking that each `s.send()` actually sends a "packet" to the destination (ip, port)!

Can someone explain to me why the second code is working correctly?

> ```
> import socket
> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> s.connect(('', 4001))
>
> uname = raw_input('enter username>')
> s.send(uname)
>
> passw = raw_input('enter password>')
> s.send(passw)
>
> print 'exiting ...'
> s.close()
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.SOCK_STREAM` means you're communicating via TCP . This means, if you call `send`, your data is pushed to the system's networking stack. Both `send` calls are called shortly one after another.

If you use TCP, your system decides about the packet size. So the `uname` and `passw` might be sent in one packet or even split in any other way.

On the receiver's side, `data1` receives up to 64 bytes, which is enough for `uname` and `passw`.

The explanation above also shows, why the second one works:

Here you need some time between sending `uname` and `passw`. During this time, your OS decides to send the packet (i.e. to flush the network buffer).

When you are using streams, you should not think in terms of packets but in terms of streams. There a `send` call only means: push some data on my network stack(like a pipeline).

If you are interested in packets,
you might try to experiment with UDP:

```
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

With such kind of socket your first sender would work as expected

Comment: Really helpful :)
Is there a way that control the "network buffer"? for example flushing buffer when needed.
Is there a good way to handle sending and receiving in socket programming in python?
somewhere in a simple framework i read a code like this:   
s = socket(...)  
s.makefile(rw, 0 )  
s.read(64) # for receiving  
s.write(64) # for sending  


Is this a better way to works with sockets??

Comment: Even if there were, there are only few scenarios where you want to control it. The point in TCP is that it controls if the packets arrive, keeps the right order and so on. Even if you flushed this buffer, it could happen that the responder demands the sender to split the packets into smaller pieces. That is why you should not consider the send call as sending packets. Just imagine a stream. Your specific problem could be solved if you introduce a separator between uname and password and split the message you receive by that separator

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem. Then I implemented a protocol to send and receive one message at a time. Hope this link will help a lot : [LINK](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html)

Comment: thanks (: i guess in this framework, [link](http://cs.berry.edu/~nhamid/p2p/btpeer.py) the author uses similar method that you suggested (look at recvdata method on BTPeerConnection class)  
 this is a simple way (: